# Remove String from JSON

Tags: javascript, json, rest, dojo, dijit.form

I want to feed a dijit.form.Select (Dojo Select-Box) with a Data-Store (JsonRest). The Problem is, that the JSON-Parser only accepts JSON in this format:

```
[
  {id:"1", name:"One1"},
  {id:"2", name:"Two1"}
];
```

The REST-API of the webapplication we want to call delivers the following JSON:

```
{
  "data": [
      {id:"1", name:"One1"},
      {id:"2", name:"Two1"}
],
    "total": 2,
    "start": 0,
    "sort": "name",
    "order": "asc",
     "size": 2
};
```

That is why the Select Box does not show any data. Therefore, we need to remove the {"data": part and the last part of the JSON message bevore passing it to the Dojo Select Box.

The Data is stored in a JsonRest Object. So the question is how we can remove the first and the last part of the JSON in a way that simply this here is given to the Select-Box:

```
[
  {id:"1", name:"One1"},
  {id:"2", name:"Two1"}
];
```

Thank you for your answers and best regards
Ben

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new Array variable from the data for the dojo select seems simplest ...

```
var restapidataObj = {
  "data": [
      {id:"1", name:"One1"},
      {id:"2", name:"Two1"}
    ],
    "total": 2,
    "start": 0,
    "sort": "name",
    "order": "asc",
     "size": 2
};

var dojoSelectArray = restapidataObj.data;
```

Now pass `dojoSelectArray` to dojo

Answer (score 1):

Store the result in a object and access the data property of that object.

```
var result = {
  "data": [
  {id:"1", name:"One1"},
  {id:"2", name:"Two1"}
],
   "total": 2,
   "start": 0,
   "sort": "name",
   "order": "asc",
   "size": 2
};
```

`result.data` would give you the `data` array.

Check the javascript object documentation at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Comment: Ok, but I need to remove the "data" : [ part and the last part of the message. Otherwise, the Dojo Selectbox won´t display any content. The question is how can I remove the "data" : [ string from my JSON?

Comment: `result.data` would give you `[
  {id:"1", name:"One1"},
  {id:"2", name:"Two1"}
]`

Comment: Thank you. How can I load the data from a JsonRest into an object?

Answer (score 0):

resultFromServer =

```
     {
       "data": [
           {id:"1", name:"One1"},
           {id:"2", name:"Two1"}
     ],
         "total": 2,
         "start": 0,
         "sort": "name",
         "order": "asc",
          "size": 2
     };
```

this convert to object (Use this incase  resultFromServer is a string)

```
    var Output = eval('('+ resultFromServer+')')
```

this gives your output

```
    JSON.stringify(Output.data)
```

gives the string

```
    "[{"id":"1","name":"One1"},{"id":"2","name":"Two1"}]"
```