# Loading JSON from Dojo JsonRest into object variable

Tags: javascript, json, rest, dojo

According to this post [Remove String from JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22377359/remove-string-from-json), I want to fill a Dojo Selectbox with JSON Data. The Problem is that I have to change the JSON Data before I can handout the data to the dijit.form.select Box.

I get the data via JsonRest. The question if, how I can load the Json Data into a normal object variable? I tried this here but it did not work.

```
var processStore = new JsonRest({
            target: "http://cnwin.ebusiness.local/activiti-rest/service/repository/process-definitions?startableByUser=kermit", 
            headers: {"Authorization": "Basic a2VybWl0Omtlcm1pdA=="}, 
            allowNoTrailingSlash: false
            });

var processes = processStore.query("",{});
```

I simply want to load the JSON data from the JsonRest store in a normal variable.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `JsonRest` store only accepts an array, so you're not able to retrieve the data, because your store is not able to read that data for you.

If you're only interested in reading the data (so no updating/creating/deleting has to be done), the easiest way is to retrieve that data using an AJAX request and manually put it inside a `dojo/store/Memory` store, for example:

```
require([ "dojo/request/xhr", "dojo/store/Memory" ], function(xhr) {
    var url = "http://cnwin.ebusiness.local/activiti-rest/service/repository/process-definitions?startableByUser=kermit";

    xhr(url, {
        handleAs: json
    }).then(function(data) {
        if (data.data !== undefined) {
            var myStore = new Memory({
                data: data.data
            });
            // Do something with "myStore"
    });
});
```

If you're interested in the full capabilities of the `JsonRest` store, you will have to extend it by yourself. If you look at [the code](https://github.com/dojo/dojo/blob/master/store/JsonRest.js) you can see several AJAX requests, in:

- `get()`
- `put()`
- `remove()`
- `query()`

Now you can write your own store and extend those methods.